# Backup partition in LVM using Clonezilla

Tags: lvm, clonezilla

I installed a Debian Jessie machine on a 1.4TB disk (technically a hardware RAID but this shouldn't matter). At installation, I created an unencrypted LVM with 3 volumes, including a 30 GB volume I installed the system on.

I want to backup the system, so I picked Clonezilla to backup the 30 GB partition.

Unfortunately, Clonezilla only offers me to clone /dev/sda, that is the whole 1.4 TB partition. As if it didn't recognize the LVM.

Is there some specific procedure to follow?

I don't see anything in the docs/FAQ so I assume it should be straightforward.

Comment: is this lvm1 or lvm2? also, what version of clonezilla?

Comment: LVM2 and I think I picked latest Clonezilla version. Should be around 2.4.2-56 or 2.4.2-59 judging by the [changelog](http://www.clonezilla.org/downloads/stable/changelog.php). I haven't tried since then.

Comment: I more or less gave up. I should be able to recreate the system thanks to the notes I took about its installation, plus I'm using etckeeper and apt-clone.